# Directive does not get updated when new records are added

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

I've created a simple directive that shows all the movies in my movies scope

```
app
  .directive('movieOverview', function () {
    return {
      template: '<div ng-repeat="movie in movies">Name: {{movie.title}}</div>',
      controller: 'searchCtrl',
    };
  });
```

But when I add my directive to my `application.html.erb` it doesn't get updated when a new record is added to the movie scope. I have to refresh the page to see the new records.

I thought directives could be used outside of scopes etc.

This is the addMovie function from my searchCtrl (which I use with the directive).

```
  $scope.addMovie = function() {

    'http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/206647?api_key=a8f7039633f2065942cd8a28d7cadad4&append_to_response=releases'
    // Search for release dates using the ID.
    var base = 'http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/';
    var movieID = $(event.currentTarget).parent().find('.movieID').text()
    var apiKey = 'a8f7039633f2065942cd8a28d7cadad4&query='
    var append_to_response = '&append_to_response=releases'
    var callback = 'JSON_CALLBACK'; // provided by angular.js
    var url = base + movieID + '?api_key=' + apiKey + append_to_response + '&callback=' + callback;

    $http.jsonp(url,{ cache: true}).
      success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

        if (status == 200) {

          $scope.movieListID = data;
          console.log($scope.movieListID);

          var releaseNL;

          for (var i = 0; i < $scope.movieListID.releases.countries.length; i++) {
            var release = $scope.movieListID.releases.countries[i];
            if (release['iso_3166_1'] == 'NL') {
                releaseNL = release;
            }
          }

          if(typeof releaseNL === 'undefined'){
            // With release date

            Notification($scope.movieListID.original_title + ' is toegevoegd, maar heeft nog geen Nederlandse premiere datum.');

            createMovie.create({
              title:          $scope.movieListID.original_title,
              release_date:   $scope.movieListID.release_date,
              image:          $scope.movieListID.poster_path,
              movie_id:       $scope.movieListID.id
            }).then(init);

          } else {
            Notification.success($scope.movieListID.original_title + ' is toegevoegd.');

            createMovie.create({
              title:          $scope.movieListID.original_title,
              release_date:   releaseNL.release_date,
              image:          $scope.movieListID.poster_path,
              movie_id:       $scope.movieListID.id
            }).then(init);
          };
```

Important to see here is the `.then(init);`

```
var init = function(){

    movieService.loadMovies().then(function(response) {
      $scope.movies = response.data;
    });

  }
  init();
```

I add a movie and then do the init function which fires a service called loadMovies

```
.factory('movieService', ['$http', function($http) {
  return {
    loadMovies: function() {
      return $http.get('/movies.json');
    }
  };
}])
```

Which requests the new movies and then updates the view.

Comment: can you add the code where you add the movie to your scope?

Comment: @thsorens I've added the code from my controller.

Comment: i would probably look for caching in your json file. Instead of reloading everything, why don't you just push the result into your movies-list? $scope.movies.push(thenewmovie);

Comment: Could you expand a bit on your suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

```
var newMovie = {
          title:          $scope.movieListID.original_title,
          release_date:   $scope.movieListID.release_date,
          image:          $scope.movieListID.poster_path,
          movie_id:       $scope.movieListID.id
        };          

createMovie.create(newMovie).then(function(){
    $scope.movies.push(newMovie);
});
```

you can also try to do something like this in your directive:

```
scope: {
  movies: '=movies'
},
```

This creates a two-way binding

Comment: Both suggestion dont' seem to work. When I add a new record the view doesn't get updated.